# double outer join?

Tags: sql, join, outer-join, cross-join

I have what I think is a fairly simple problem, but i'm missing something.

I have 3 tables :

```
t_users : user_id, user_name
t_users_modules : user_id, module_id
t_modules : module_id, module_name
```

I'd like to output a list of all `module_name`, for each `user_name`, and check if this user indeed have this right in the `t_users_modules` table.

Is it a cross join ? I've never used it.

I tried with 2 left outer join without success.

Comment: Please add what ever you have tried so far in the question

Comment: Can you please add a sample with input and expected output?

Comment: SQL Server? Oracle? MySQL? Other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you use a cross-join to generate all of the possibilities and then a left join to test for the presence or absence of the required row:

```
select module_name, user_name,
     CASE WHEN um.user_id is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as HasRight
from
   t_users u
       cross join
   t_modules m
       left join
   t_user_modules um
       on
           u.user_id = um.user_id and
           m.module_id = um.module_id
```

Incidentally, if you're using `t_` as some form of prefix to identify tables, I'd recommend dropping it - in almost all places in SQL, the type of the object is identifiable from where the object appears in the statement. The only general exception is that tables and views are indistinguishable - but that's a good thing - they shouldn't generally be distinguished between.

Comment: What extra does a CROSS JOIN contribute with in this specific case? (I've got a feeling that OP doesn't really know what he/she is asking for when mentioning the term cross join.)

Comment: Found the answer too.
It was a cross join. Did the test with a subquery though, but your answer is "cleaner". 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: @jarlh - because it sounds to me like the OP *wants* to generate the cartesian join between the `users` and `modules` tables.

Comment: Well, you may absolutely be right, it's sometimes hard to understand the real problem, what the OP really is asking for.

Comment: Yes, I wanted the cartesian join, without knowing it. I was on the right track with cross join.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.user_name,t3.module_name,
CASE WHEN t1.user_id is not null then 1 else 0 end as "Has Right"
from t_users t1
join t_users_modules t2
on(t1.user_id=t2.user_id)
join t_modules  t3
on (t2.module_id=t3.module_id);
```